# Помогите исправить ошибку "TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: "

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Почему когда я пытаюсь передать функции `async def on_raw_reaction_add` более одного аргумента появляется такая ошибка: 
`TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'` 
Сам код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload, ctx):
    print("test")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Если оставить только один аргумент, например `payload` то все работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргументы функции передаете не вы, а `Discord API`, при вызове функции из чата дискорда.

Смотрим в [**документацию**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_react#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) и видим, что функция `on_raw_reaction_add()` принимает только один аргумент - `payload`. Поэтому, когда вы пытаетесь передать еще и `ctx`, Python сообщает вам, что функция не получила 1 аргумент. А не получила именно потому, что его не отправлял `Discord API`.

---

Наверное, пытаясь принять аргумент `ctx`, вы хотели получить контекст команды, как у команд с декоратором `client.command()`. Здесь, вместо него передается `payload`, из которого тоже можно получить все [**`необходимые данные`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_react#discord.RawReactionActionEvent):

```
payload.channel_id - id канала, в сообщении которого была добавлена реакция
payload.emoji      - объект эмоджи; для получения символа примените str(payload.emoji)
payload.event_type - тип события (подробнее в документации)
payload.guild_id   - id сервера, в сообщении которого была добавлена реакция
payload.member     - объект участника сервера, который добавил реакцию
payload.message_id - id сообщения, для которого была добавлена реакция
payload.user_id    - id пользователя, который добавил реакцию
```

А сами объекты можем получать уже из ID:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
emoji = str(payload.emoji)
guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
member = payload.member  
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
user = await client.fetch_user(payload.user_id )
```

---

Ну и если сильно хочется, можно назвать аргумент `payload` как `ctx`. `Discord API` все равно передаст один и тот же объект. **Главное, не забывайте, что этот `ctx` не будет иметь те же объекты, что и контекст команды**

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(ctx):
    print(ctx.channel_id)
```

Comment: Все, понял, спасибо вам огромное!